# Sublime math scope confused with tabu

Tags: sublime-text, scoping

I'm trying to use Sublime Text 3 for writing LaTeX docs.
Unfortunately writing a tabu with a math column `X[$]` confuses the scoping mechanism as one can see in the screenshots. Note that the code in the screenshot is just for demonstrating purpose.

Is there any way to avoid the confusion?

[image: example]
[image: scopes]

**Edit** I'm using LaTeXTools

Comment: Which latex package are you using? LaTeXtools, latexing, or some other?

Comment: @Holene Im using LaTeXTools

Comment: Am I understanding you correctly if you don't have any compilation problems (assuming `\usepackage{tabu}` is inserted), you just want the color scheme to pick up the `tabu` math column?

Comment: @Holene Yes, there are no compilation problems. But scope sensitive auto completions are useless when Sublime handles non-mathscope as mathscope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made it.

I Hope this will not throw any other scope confusions in the future. Here is my solution (note that I'm working on a windows 8.1 machine):

1. Open your Sublime Text 3 installation directory and in it the Packages directory. On my machine it is `C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\Packages`
2. In this directory open (e.g. with 7-Zip) the package `LaTeX.sublime-package` (make a backup of this file before)
3. In this package you can see a file called `TeX.tmLanguage`. Copy this file to your desktop (or anywhere else).
4. Open this copied `TeX.tmLanguage` file with Sublime. In my file there is from line 165 to line 205 the *dict* entry for the scope named `string.other.math.tex` (this information is in line 186-187).
   At the beginning of this *dict* entry (line 166-167) we have the *begin key*, and the string is simply `\$`, telling Sublime Text 3 "here starts a `string.other.math.tex` scope. This is a regular expression in the onigurama syntax (see [here](http://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/extensibility/syntaxdefs.html#analyzing-patterns) and [here](http://www.geocities.jp/kosako3/oniguruma/doc/RE.txt)).
5. Replace the `\$` with the following regex: `(?&lt;!X\[)(?&lt;!X\[[\w\.-])(?&lt;!X\[[\w\.-]{2})(?&lt;!X\[[\w\.-]{3})(?&lt;!X\[[\w\.-]{4})(?&lt;!X\[[\w\.-]{5})(?&lt;!X\[[\w\.-]{6})(?&lt;!X\[[\w\.-]{7})\$`
   This regex is xml escaped and basicaly a negative lookbehind guaranteeing that what precedes the `$` is not any pattern of the tabu column type `X[coef,align,type]` with up to 7 chars (e.g. `X[-1.25cb$]`). If somebody knows a smarter regex I would appreciate.
6. Save and close the file. Close Sublime Text 3 also. Now copy the edited `TeX.tmLanguage` file into the `LaTeX.sublime-package` package (which is possible through 7-Zip). This will override the old `TeX.tmLanguage` file.

Now Sublime Text should be able to cope with the math scope.

---

### Edit

After a Windows reinstallation I tried my given steps again and recognized, that I'm not able to copy the edited `TeX.tmLanguage` file back into the `LaTeX.sublime-package` package. So I had to research the reason and found the statement that the packages in the `C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\Packages` folder are read only. But there is a possibility to override certain files in those packages. Here are the [steps](http://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/extensibility/packages.html#overriding-packages):

1. In your user directory of Sublime Text 3 create a folder called `LaTeX`
2. Copy the modified `TeX.tmLanguage` file (see above) into this folder.

Now this file in the `User\LaTeX` folder gets precedence over the same file in the `C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\Packages` folder.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't really answer your question, but it might solve your problem. How about avoid the entire problem by just defining a new column type?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabu}

\newcolumntype{M}{>{$}X<{$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabu}
  {X M}
  a & x^2
\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm sorry I don't have an answer for how Sublime Text handles it's scopes. You probably need to define some exception from `$ ... $` defining a math scope (maybe in the `yourTheme.tmTheme` file) for `X[$]`. I don't possess the xml-skills needed!

Comment: Of course, this will prevent the scope confusion. But I would need to change several docs afterwards. As you mentioned, an exception for `X[$]` would be nice, but I also don't know how to.

Comment: You could use the "mark all" option (ctrl+cmd+g for mac) in Sublime and replace all occurrences when you're working in a new document with your problem. But yes, I understand this is suboptimal :-)